# How can I stop the iPhone from displaying a transform change until after the screen is redrawn

Tags: iphone

I have found the UIScrollView's zooming mechanism to be clunk and essentially unusable.  So instead, I'm rolling my own.  I have a UIView that resizes itself with the pinch-zoom, and that's working fine.  When the zoom is complete, the view needs to reset its transform and redraw the images.

The zoom works essentially in the same way the UIScrollView does.  It sets the `transform` property of the UIView until complete.  Then, when the zoom finishes, I want to reset the `transform` to `CGAffineTransformIdentity`, resize the frame to be the size it was before, and tell the view to redraw itself at the new size.

It all works pretty well, except when I change the transform to identity then redraw the image, there is a slight flicker before the image completely redraws.  This is due to the fact that I'm using a subclass of CATiledLayer, since the view can be of arbitrary size.

I've overridden the `fadeDuration` to be zero, but there is still a flicker while the transform is reset before the redraw is finished.  Is there any simple way to overcome this without creating another view to draw with then replacing it?

Comment: Ed, are you still having problems with this? I've found UIScrollView largely unusable unless you combine it with CATiledLayer, and vice versa. In other words, if you're using a CATiledLayer anyway, use a UIScrollView!

Comment: I believe I'm not having this problem anymore, as I don't recall having seen it lately;  There are most definitely other issues with using a UIScrollView in my case that make using a regular UIView much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved using a lower-level approach to layers.